get current tab lang from outl1ne/nova-translatable
Would it be possible to do something like that using https://github.com/outl1ne/nova-translatable?
 Select::make('Product', 'product')->options(
   function () {
        //get product if database field "langs_enabled" have the current language tab
        }
   )->nullable()->translatable(),

I know how to do the query, but I don't know if it is possible to obtain the language of the tab. Does anyone know how to do it?
